# Assistance using SOCKET.IO to connect a JAVA Client and a HTML/JAVASCRIPT Server

Tags: javascript, java, html, socket.io, connection

I'm working on a JAVA system that needs to pass a string over to a website so that the website can display it in the  of it. I've done some research and for my issue the SOCKET.IO extension seems to be the solution but I can't seem to get it working on the website end. (Using https://socketio.github.io/socket.io-client-java/emitting_events.html on the JAVA end, mainly following the template) I'm not very good with website setup so I don't know the best way to set up the server side in JAVASCRIPT, is there any way I could please get assistance setting it up via my localhost:3000? As far as I know, the HTML/CSS doesn't really matter here as it's all done via the JAVASCRIPT so I don't think I need to show that, but feel free to ask for it. (I have no JAVASCRIPT written currently, I tried a bit but it was a mess)

Thank you for any help that can be provided, I know it's a bit specific.

Comment: Why do you need a JavaScript server?

Comment: As far as I know, that's the only proper way I can get the string passed over to the website as both the JAVA system and the website would be on at the same time.

Comment: You would then need another client in JavaScript, because the server has to run on the backend. I would suggest setting up the server in Java and if socket.io for Java doesn't allow that, I would just use plain web sockets.